# c# Linq to SQL and Generics

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, generics

Im quite new to generics and as a learning exercise Im trying to create a simple method that picks an entity from an entity set (table) with a specified ID.

```
    public T GetEntity<T>(int id) where T : class
    {
        return db.GetTable<T>().SingleOrDefault(o => o.id == id); 
    }
```

The above obviously wont work because `o` in `o.id` is unknown and thus cannot access the property `id` - can someone help with how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot change your entity classes (for implementing a common interface), you could use a predicate function and pass it into the method

```
public T GetEntity<T>(int id, Func<T, int, bool> predicate) where T : class
{
    return db.GetTable<T>().SingleOrDefault(o => predicate(o,id));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If all of your entities contain an `id` property then you can define an interface

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int id { get; }
}
```

implement it on all your classes and change your method to

```
public T GetEntity<T>(int id) where T : IEntity
{
    return db.GetTable<T>().SingleOrDefault(o => o.id == id); 
}
```

Such interface can be useful in all the places where you want to do something for all your entities, ie. Delete by id. You can add more properties to your interface, ie. timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, **not recommended** for performance reasons, but i shall post it anyway.

```
public T GetEntity<T>(int id) where T : class 
    { 

        return db.GetTable<T>().AsEnumerable().SingleOrDefault(o => (int)o.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(o,null) == id);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a constrain on your T so the compiler can be sure there is a id property. Once way is to use interfaces, ie.

```
public interface IUnique 
{
   int id { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can say

```
public T GetEntity<T>(int id) where T : class, IUnique
{
    return db.GetTable<T>().SingleOrDefault(o => o.id == id); 
}
```